# How to use the rebind of Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dynamic-rebinding

I have followed multiple tutorial to do a rebind interface for ma game.
However, It is not working.

To check if it worked, I made this script:

[image]

I am using the rebind UI asset from the Input system package.

[image]

[image]

Here is an exemple of the button to change the key.
The key change in the UI but not in the Player Input Action.

Please help me.
Have a good day.